# Bucketing in Hive Internal Table and SparkSql

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have created a bucketed internal hive table through the dataframe writer saveAsTable api.

```
df.repartition(numBuckets, somecol)
              .write()
              .format("parquet")
              .bucketBy(numBuckets,col1)
              .sortBy(col1)
              .saveAsTable(hiveTableName);
```

Now I trigger 2 select queries via spark sql , one on the buckted column and the other on the non bucketed column but I don't see any difference in the execution time.

The queries are :
select * from t1 where col1='123' [t1 is bucketed by col1]
select * from t1 where col2='123' [col2 is not a bucketing column]
My questions are

1. How can I ascertain that during the query execution full table scan is happening or partial table scan on the relevant is happening?
2. Can I get any information from the DAG or the physical plan? I have seen both ,but I don't see any difference
   This what I see in the physical plan

   == Physical Plan ==
   *(1) Project [col1#0, col2#1, col3#2, col4#3, col5#4, col6#5, col7#6, col8#7, col9#8, col10#9, col11#10, col12#11]
   +- *(1) Filter (isnotnull(col2#1) && (col2#1 = 123))
   +- *(1) FileScan parquet default.uk_geocrosswalk[col1#0,col2#1,col3#2,col4#3,col5#4,col6#5,col7#6,col8#7,col9#8,LSOA_MSOA_WEIGHT#9,col11#10,col12#11] Batched: true, Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[hdfs://url/a.parquet, PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(col2), EqualTo(col2,123)], ReadSchema: struct
3. In the physical plan why is it doing a file scan ? Should not it be doing a HiveTableScan as the table has been created as a hive table?
4. Are there certain config parameters that I can use to tune my queries while using sparksql ?
5. I see each time I run the query for the first time in spark sql it takes considerably long time. Is there a way I can warmup the executors before the query gets executed ?

Answer (score 1):

Parquet is columnar. Parquet is very fast from my experience. The columnar aspect may well explain the same performance - whether key or not, the data format physically is columnar.

It is a Hive table, but using Parquet and Bucketing and not accessible to Hive / Impala. As it is Parquet, Hive Table Scan is not appropriate. A Hive table can have many physical formats, text, Parquet, ORC.

You can see the filtering: **PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(col2), EqualTo(col2,123)],**

No warmup as such. You could .cache things but I have tested and seen tests whereby there is not much difference in terms of caching Parquet tables, but it depends on the test.

Comment: but why is the partitionFilter blank? I have stored the data clustered via a column

Comment: Maybe there ar bugs but it makes sense to me. Some ofoutputnot so easy to interprete